# npm hangs pulling dependencies from artifactory

Tags: npm, artifactory, npm-install

Our developers pull all of their npm dependencies via an artifactory proxy.  The artifactory setup uses a virtual repository that consists of a local npm repository and a remote npm repository.

When developers perform an npm install, the process is slow and often hangs at

`fetchMetadata -> network`

Any ideas on tracing the source of this issue?

Does artifactory provide a 'trace' api for npm resources, similar to what they have for maven dependencies here [maven trace](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-TraceArtifactRetrieval)?

Would re-indexing the virtual repository on artifactory help?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue and I don't have a solution or an idea on how to debug or identify the issue.  I've used verbose output and I didn't get any additional information from npm.

Comment: What version of Artifactory are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Struggled with the same thing. By adding the debug flag when running install helped me. I don't know why, might be some race condition or to many half open connections or something else. When the debug flag is added each step takes a fraction of a second longer to complete, and that seems to be enough. Here's an example for a local package:

```
npm install -d
```

or a longer example:

```
sudo npm install -g -ddd eslint-cli
```

The number of `d`'s tells npm how verbose debug you want. More `d`'s means more info and longer time to execute. One `d` did it for me, but my laptop is slow to begin with.